# Largest and smallest random number C#

Tags: c#, random, numbers

The program ask the user next question:

What is the minimum and maximum of any 4 numbers (generated randomly by the
program?

The program should check the user answer (true or false).

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It's pretty obvious from the copy/paste nature of your question that it's an assignment question. We don't mind helping with those but the way it's formatted at the moment is a "do it for me" which we're not here to do. If we were, we'd get the degree at the end ;). Update you question with some examples of what you've tried and we'll help if we can

Answer (score -2):

Without knowing much about how the code will flow, here is a mix of code and pseudo-code that should get you pointed in the right direction.

```
List<int> intList = new List<int>();
// code to add number to the list here
int minNumAnswer = user min num answer;
int maxNumAnswer = user max num answer; 
maxNumAnswer == intList.Max(); // will evaluate to true or false;
minNumAnswer ==  intList.Min();
```

Comment: C'mon man, what are they going to learn if they don't even try? I don't mind folk that help out clearly panicked students that are looking for help but the OP's question is just sheer laziness and should be discouraged. Lazy homework problems are like Hyrda: `Do one today, two more shall take it's place`

Comment: I'm just trying to point someone that asked a question in the right direction.

Comment: Bad questions shouldn't really be answered. Occasionally people do, and that's fine, but doing homework for others is strongly discouraged. Why? Because they'll end up graduating/getting a job that they might be qualified for but they sure as fate aren't remotely competent in (and we have **far too many** incompetent developers out there). You can point the OP in the right direction using comments (which is advised for questions of this sort) rather than an answer.